# jQuery get next() or prev() attribute alt text from image inside ul li

Tags: jquery, css

I have some problems with some custom made carousel logic.

I need to handle two events on my page. When the users press left i want the selector to be the previous object to the active one. And when user press right the active item should be next to the "active" one.

This is the html

```
<li><a href='/vaara'><img src="/media/954/150.jpg" alt="blabla"/></a></li> 
<li><a href='/vaara'><img src="/media/954/150.jpg" alt="blabla"/></a></li>
<li><a href='/vaara'><img src="/media/954/150.jpg" alt="blabla"/></a></li>
```

The element in the middle represent the "active" one.

This is the jquery i have come up with

```
var activeitem = $("#carousel_ul li:eq(3) a img", this).attr('alt');
```

And now i just would like to get the prev() or next() alt text. Something like this

```
carouselItemLeft.on('click', function () {
                    var connectedInsurace = activeitem.next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` looks at the very next sibling. Your current context is an image, the "next" image you want is a wrapped in a list item and anchor, so you need something like:

```
var next = activeItem.closest("li").next().find("img").attr("alt");
```

Answer (score 1):

`eq` is zero-based so `:eq(3)` selects the third `li` element which doesn't exist in your markup and `attr` returns `undefined`. `next` is a jQuery object's method not String object and in your code results in a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Yeah i know eq is zero-based. This was just an example trying to illustrate what i was wanting to do. I think you understood that

Comment: @rickard Please provide more code, where `carouselItemLeft` has been defined?

Comment: `var carouselItemLeft = $('#carousel_container .carousel-item-left');`

Answer (score 0):

You should name your variables to reflect what they actually are. `activeitem` shouldn't store to the `alt` atribute of the item, it should store the actual item.

Let's assume that the currently active `li` element has a class called `active`. Then your code might look like:

```
carouselItemLeft.on('click', function () {
    var $activeitem = $("#carousel_ul li.active"); // the li, not the img
    var $connectedInsurace = $activeitem.next();
    var alttext = activeitem.find('img').attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're best off actually assigning a data-* tag to the active item instead of using indexes on your items.

So:

```
carouselItemLeft.on('click', function () {
      var $connectedInsurace = $('[data-active="true"]');
      $connectedInsurace.data("active", false);
      $(this).data("active", true);

     // Get next item
     var $next = $connectedInsurace.next();
});
```